# Epidermolysis bullosa and getting nails done

Tags: nails, epidermolysis-bullosa

I have Epidermolysis Bullosa, and I'm 20 years old. I have never (but always wanted to) had my nails done by a professional. Having E.B means I've lost a nail and 3 are only half there.

Given this, I was wondering if anyone out there knows whether or not it should be OK?

I'm very un-confident so you wouldn't see my walking into a nail salon and just asking there and then.

Answer (score 0):

My wife has RDEB and has occasionally had her nails done (french manicure) without problems.  However you do have to ask them to be a bit more slow and gentle than normal, otherwise it is painful and might cause a blister.  You might want to explain the condition to them so they are aware of why you are asking them to do is more carefully.

It would also depend on whether your hands tend to usually blister or not.  My wife's hands don't tend to blister (and is missing one nail), but if yours do blister it might be a bit more risky.